# Is there a database containing typical transistor data and characteristics?

Tags: transistors, datasheet, data

I guess the title says all, but basically I'm looking for a searchable database on typical transistors' data. Such data would ideally be arranged like:

`Name Type VCEO VCBO VEBO IC hFE fT ... etc ... etc`

That could be an Excel spreadsheet, no problem.

PDF Datasheets are widely available, but I would like to have all info in the same document. I know it ain't easy, but who knows.

Thanks.

Comment: Many distributors, such as Mouser and Digikey, have this information as part of their parametric search feature.

Comment: @Hearth I know Mouser and it's indeed a great resource, but my main intent was having the raw data so that I could build my own search/selection tools. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Export the Mouser / Digikey data to a spread sheet.  Then you can do what you want with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into simulator packages, e.g. LTspice. They do have a large assortment of transistors to choose from, so they have all that info (and maybe much more, for simulating minor transistor behaviour quirks).

It will need some work to convert it from their format, to the one you want though.

See the following screenshot from the "pick transistor" dialog:
[image]

Comment: Very nice. I had heard of LTspice, but didn't know it was freeware. The database on transistors is quite good, albeit not too comprehensive. But it's a great start. Thanks!